# does airflow dag bash operator have command length limitation ? if so , what can we do to extend it?

Tags: bash, command, airflow, task, directed-acyclic-graphs

In our dag we have a task like the below:

```
task1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='xxyz', 
    bash_command='echo $y |base64 -d > task.py; command1 ; command 2; \
        ....\
        ...\
    command N; ', 
)
```

as so many commands there, so when we add one more command N+1 to this task's BashOperator, then Airflow can not run this code but still run the old code end with "command N;". I think we reach the length #limitation of the bash_command.
Is there a way to extend this limitation? thanks.

I have try to reduce the length of the bash_command then it is working, but if the bash_command is too long then it will not pickup the code change of the related task.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try including all your commands in a shell script and execute it?

```
task2 = BashOperator(
    task_id="bash_example",
    # This works (has a space after)
    bash_command="/home/batcher/test.sh ",
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: my customers does not wana put all the commands in a shell scripts.